# Python script not opening file when using Selenium

Tags: python, unit-testing, io

I've been coding Selenium unittests using Python. I'm trying to write an output to a file, but for some reason, my code isn't even opening the file. The same code works when I use it in the command line, but nothing happens when I run it with my seltest. Is there some kind of restriction in the Webdriver API that prevents me from doing this? I'm not getting any errors either.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

~Carpetfizz

```
def mailGen(self):
        self.email = "tester%s@example.com" % floor(uniform(1,10)*100)
        logFile = open('log.txt','w')
        logFile.write('')
        logFile.write(self.email)
        logFile.close()
        return self.email
```

I've pretty much copy and pasted this code into the console, as you can see below, and it is working perfectly. Except for the fact that it is opening the file in my `C:/Python33` directory, which is expected.

```
>>> def mailGen():
        email = "tester%s@example.com" % floor(uniform(1,10)*100)
        logFile = open('log.txt','w')
        logFile.write('')
        logFile.write(email)
        logFile.close()
        return email

>>> mailGen()
'tester508@example.com'
>>> mailGen()
'tester827@example.com'
>>>
```

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you posted. Please show us how the function `mailGen` is getting called.

Comment: `textField_email.send_keys(self.mailGen())` is how it is getting called. `textField_email` is a valid element on the DOM, and it does send the keys generated by `mailGen()`.

Comment: Perhaps supply a full path on the line: `logFile = open('/full/path/to/log.txt', 'w')`. Your current code may be writing to some directory other than the one you are expecting it to write to.

Comment: Hmm, when I do this, I'm getting `(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape (<pyshell#40>, line 1)` as an alert. Also, I would like for it to be in the existing directory, since the code will be used on UNIX systems as well.

Comment: Try: `logFile.write(email.encode('utf-8'))` to address the unicode error. Since you are using Python3, `email = "..."` makes `email` a `unicode`. `unicode`s need to be encoded as `bytes` before they can be written to a file.

Comment: Thanks much. The issue ended up being something silly on my part. I had copied my file to a git repo, and I kept opening the old one from my "Recent Files", and it was creating files in the old directory. Works fine now. Thanks again for the useful info, I will reference it in the future.